# Выбрать несколько значений из базы данных с одним id

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется БД сайта (магазина) на umi.cms. Мне надо при помощи php вытащить оттуда наименование товара и все картинки к нему, а затем сложить всё это в массив. Наименования и изображения хранятся в 2х разных таблицах. В таблице с изображениями имеется obj_id, который собственно привязывает изображения к товарам
[image: скрин из phpMyAdmin]

Сейчас я обращаюсь к базе данных и записываю значения в массив при помощи следующего кода:

```
    $sql = "SELECT cms3_objects.type_id, cms3_objects.id, cms3_objects.name, cms3_object_images.src
FROM cms3_objects JOIN cms3_object_images
WHERE cms3_object_images.field_id = 300 && cms3_objects.id = cms3_object_images.obj_id || 
cms3_object_images.field_id = 485 && cms3_objects.id = cms3_object_images.obj_id
LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if ($rs_result) {
        $response["results"] = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {
            $product = array();
            $product["type_id"] = $row["type_id"];
            $product["id"] = $row["id"];
            $product["name"] = $row["
            $product["img_url"] = $row["src"]);
            array_push($response["results"], $product);
        }
}
```

Но это не позволяет мне к одному id сложить несколько изображений.
Как можно это реализовать? 
Прошу подробных ответов, так как php мне пришлось применить впервые на этой задаче.

Выполнение функции `print_r($row);`
[image: выполнение print_r($row);]

Comment: Складывайте в массив, учитывая дублирование id. Я вам советую так `$response["results"][$row["id"]][] = $row;`. Дальше, думаю, разберётесь

Comment: Это не решает моей задачи, т.к. судя по всему, нужно редактировать сам запрос к БД. Я так думаю, потому как если набрать `print_r($row);` , видно, что даже в этом массиве выводится всего 1 ссылка на изображение. Прикреплю скрин выполнения данной функции к телу вопроса.

Comment: Так и должно быть. И как бы вы не меняли запрос, так и будет. Вы, конечно, можете сделать "implode" по колонке и получить строку со всеми ссылками, но это моветон. Мой совет решает вашу задачу, нужно только выкинуть лишнюю информацию. Никто же не знает в каком виде вы хотите получить ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу несколько иначе, чем предлагали в комментариях. Пришлось делать второй запрос к БД, т.к. либо мы не поняли друг друга в комментариях, либо сказалось мое не знание языка программирования. Возможно не самое элегантное решение, но всё же вот оно, если кому понадобится:

```
$sql = "SELECT cms3_objects.type_id, cms3_objects.id, cms3_objects.name, 
cms3_object_images.src
FROM cms3_objects JOIN cms3_object_images
ON cms3_object_images.field_id = 300 && cms3_objects.id = cms3_object_images.obj_id 
LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if ($rs_result) {
        $response["results"] = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {
            $product = array();
            $product["type_id"] = $row["type_id"];
            $product["id"] = $row["id"];
            $product["name"] = $row["name"];

            $obj_id = $product["id"];
            $sql_img = "SELECT cms3_object_images.src, cms3_object_images.obj_id 
    FROM cms3_object_images
    WHERE cms3_object_images.obj_id = $obj_id";
            $img_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_img);
            if ($img_result){
                    $i = 0;
                    $images = array();
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($img_result)) {
                        $img_url = array();
                        $img_url[$i] = $row["src"];
                        $i++;
                        array_push($images, $img_url);
                    }
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
                    foreach ($images as $value) {
                        $product["img_url" . $i] = implode($images[$i]);
                    }
                }
                array_push($response["results"], $product);
            }
```

Можно было конечно использовать многомерный массив, но я решил упростить, используя implode, не смотря на рекомендации.